# Better way to move an Elm list element

Tags: arrays, list, elm

I have a `List` in my Elm model. On a `Drag` message containing the previous index and next index (both zero-based) of an element, I want to move the element. This is the code that I am using now. I first convert to an `Array`, then use slices to rearrange the array, finally converting back to a `List`. Is there a better way (maybe not involving arrays). Note that the list will never have more than 5 items.

```
Drag { prev, next } ->
    let
        arr =
            Array.fromList model.list

        temp =
            Array.append
                (Array.slice 0 prev arr)
                (Array.slice (prev + 1) (Array.length arr) arr)

        list_ =
            Array.toList <|
                Array.append
                    (Array.append
                        (Array.slice 0 next temp)
                        (Array.slice prev (prev + 1) arr)
                    )
                    (Array.slice next (Array.length temp) temp)

        model_ =
            { model | list = list_ }
    in
    ( model_, Cmd.none )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find yourself using [`Array.slice`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Array#slice) a lot, it's worth looking at the [`List.take`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#take) and [`List.drop`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#drop) functions to see if they can do what you need!

For your example, it can be rewritten using `List.take`, `List.drop`, and [`List.concat`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#concat):

```
Drag { prev, next } ->
    let
        item =
            List.drop prev model.list
                |> List.take 1

        rest =
            List.concat
                [ List.take prev model.list
                , List.drop (prev + 1) model.list
                ]

        reorderedList =
            List.concat
                [ List.take next rest
                , item
                , List.drop next rest
                ]

        updatedModel =
            { model | list = reorderedList }
    in
        ( updatedModel, Cmd.none )
```

I threw together a quick [demo in Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/4KvpqJBvcXsa1) that you can compare the two versions in.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I started to look at `take` and `drop`, but gave up after struggling with the indices.